# Write surrogate pairs to file using Haskell

Tags: haskell, unicode, surrogate-pairs

This is the code I have:

```
import qualified System.IO as IO

writeSurrogate :: IO ()
writeSurrogate = do
  IO.writeFile "/home/sibi/surrogate.txt" ['\xD800']
```

Executing the above code gives error:

```
text-tests: /home/sibi/surrogate.txt: commitBuffer: invalid argument (invalid character)
```

The reason being is that it is prevented by the GHC itself as they are surrogate code points: https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/21f0f56164f50844c2150c62f950983b2376f8b6/libraries/base/GHC/IO/Encoding/Failure.hs#L114

I want to write some test files which needs to have that data. Right now, I'm using Python to achieve what I want - But I would love to know if there is an way (workaround using Haskell) to achieve this.

Comment: This has to do with the encoding: in UTF-16, this is simply not a *valid* character: it does *not* map on a character.

Comment: See here: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/Unifont_Full_Map.png

Comment: You can use a "binary writer" to write the specified bytes. But as text it makes no sense.

Comment: If you want to write data that is not valid text, don't write it as text. Write as binary instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just write the bytes you want:

```
import Data.ByteString as BS
main = BS.writeFile "surrogate.txt" (pack [0xd8, 0x00])
```